# How to know whether a UITextField contains a specific character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How would I say that if a UITextField has @"-" in it, do something.
Right now my code is like this. It doesn't seem to work:

```
if (MyUITextField.text == @"-") {
    NSRange range = {0,1};
    [a deleteCharactersInRange:range];
    MyUITextField.text = MyUILabel.text;
}
```

I know that I am doing something very wrong with the code. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing `==` to `[MyUITextField.text isEqualToString:@"-"]`

as == tests to see if they are the same object, while isEqualToString compares the contents of the strings.

Comment: This checks if you input the string "-" and will return false if you put in say "foo-bar".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your string is defined as:

```
NSString *str = @"foo-bar";
```

To check if your string *contains* "-" you can do the following:

```
if ([str rangeOfString:@"-"].length > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Contains -");
}
```

It looks like you wanted to delete the first character if a string *starts with* a given character. In this case you can do something like this:

```
if ([str hasPrefix:@"f"])
{
    NSLog(@"Starts with f");
}
```